# OnClick Event To Close Session in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript

OnClick Is Not Working When I Clicked On Button

I have Provided Button Named Logout and Written an Function That needs to be performed when that button is clicked.

But when i clicked on it it's not executing the function, i checked by placing breakpoint, but breakpoint is not activated when i clicked on Logout button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top:-280px; margin-left:1100px;" onclick="Logout()">Logout</button>

<script>
    function Logout() {
        @Session["IsLoggedIn"] = false;
        @Session["RoleId"] = null;
        @Session["LoyalityPoints"] = null;
        return RedirectToAction("IndexSeachBeforeLogin");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have RedirectToAction in your javascript?

Comment: I have removed type="submit" but still it's not working

Comment: Here you are trying to set server variables form client? I am sure you might be getting some javascript error

Comment: Can you please post the source inside script after page is loaded, try inspect element

Comment: RedirectToAction is available in javascript, i removed it and tried to execute, but still it's not executing.

Comment: Error Says : Uncaught ReferenceError: Logout is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235499/discussion-between-bharat-and-ankireddypalli-harinath-reddy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **server side varaibles** sunch as `@Session["IsLoggedIn"]` to assign the value in javascript.

However, when you use such case the value of `@Session["IsLoggedIn"]` variable get's replaced during the page rendering
e.g if `@Session["IsLoggedIn"]` value is true then it would be

```
true = false;
```

This would result in javascript error and hence your code is not working.

Ideally to clear the variables values of logged in session, you must clear them from server side and not at client side.